# Zephyr API to access test steps not working

Tags: jira-zephyr

I need to access test steps of a test case.
When I tried the following URL using CURL GET request,

http:///rest/zapi/latest/teststep//

I am getting the following error message

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://<jira_server>/rest/zapi/latest/teststep/<issueId>/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at <jira_server> Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Same request using the browser gives {}
I got the issue ID using the REST API 
"https:///rest/api/2/issue/testCaseId
So I am sure that the issue Id is correct.

Is this something because of latest zephyr update? 
Can some one help me what is the issue with the request?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think you have to purchase a plugin to use the ZAPI:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.zapi

You can, however, connect to your database yourself and try to extract the test steps by looking for a table called **[SOME_PREFIX_SUCH_AS_*A7AEFBD*]_TESTSTEP** in your jira database. It holds an ID for the issue it belongs to so combining it with the **jiraissues** table you can fetch all test steps for a test issue you've made. Put that query result into an excel sheet and you have yourself a cheap extraction of your test steps.